# AJAX form submit not working on iOS devices

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Okay, so this sounds plugin-specific, but I'm hoping someone could explain WHY this might be happening.

I'm developing a site in Wordpress, and I am using two plugins, Contact Form 7, and an integrated Mailchimp plugin for CF7.

On form submit, it should serve a failure or success response via AJAX and that's that - I've never had a problem. However, on this site the data is still submitted and is working fine. However, instead of an AJAX response, the page is reloaded.

THIS IS ONLY ON iOS!!!

My first thought was that it was obviously some sort of conflict, so I deactivated my plugins, INCLUDING a jquery plugin called fullpage.js

No change, still reloads. I thought it could be to do with the version of jQuery I'm running, or how i've enqueued my scripts, but still no difference.

Does anyone have any initial ideas on what might cause this sort of issue?

UPDATE: Went back and tested on an old site that uses CF7 and has same issues on iOS (great testing, I know). So, this must be an issue with CF7 and iOS. Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: did my answer help you or solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices:

- have retired synchronous AJAX methods and only use asynchronous
- don't allow cachinig

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: your_URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception, errorThrown) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

More on this topic found [here](http://chadschroeder.blogspot.hr/2013/01/jquery-ajax-and-aggressive-ios-caching.html).

Comment: ivan86, this helped solve our ajax form post on ios safari problem.  I had temporarily had it doing traditional form post (bleh!)  Thanks so much.  I'm not sure when this change came down, because our users only periodically reported an issue.

Comment: @enorl76 I have encountered this issue about a year ago while showing one of my remote control Arduino projects to a person that had an iphone (my web application uses ajax, PHP and CORS to communicate and control the Arduino). It was quite frustrating until I got to the bottom of this! It seems this had been around for at least 5-6 years now. Glad it helped :)