# Ajax form not updating in IOS only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax form that allows use to edit a table row. Once the form is submitted and the response is received the values are updated in the table. It works seemlesly in chrome but for some reason the values are not updated in IOS (unless I refresh the page).
I read on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818112/ajax-form-submit-not-working-on-ios-devices) that you need to add `cache:false` to the code which I did but the problem persists. Any thoughts what I've got wrong?

```
$(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("data-id")
      var form = $("#edit_newcredit");

 $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType : "html",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      cache: false,
      headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );

      $("#"+id).closest('tr').next('tr').remove(); //Remove the next tr
      $("#"+id).closest('tr').replaceWith(response); //Replace the current tr

      },        
  });
});
```

Comment: If you see the update after refresh, it means `POST` was successful. I am guessing it would be something with your concatenating to make id. Make sure the value of `id` is being set. Try `var id = $(this).data("id");` for setting your variable.

Comment: You don't need `cache: false` for POST requests, they're never cached.

Comment: You don't need the `contentType` option, that's the default.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Good advice as I can now see that var id is undefined on IOS. Something to do with the rows I'm showing in mobile view. Very helpful.